# how to update an include php without refresh in all page

Tags: php, include

I need update only a part of the page where its included an include php with a specific path. How update only this file included with this include.

Code is this:

```
<tbody>
   <?php include_once "tabelas/table.php";  ?>
</tbody>
```

What I am doing in really is calling a function javascript that do update and it do update, but it not do update in this include php. Thanks advance!

(i dont want do require in ajax because it is a datatable and in this case it just work with include php, so i need a solution in php preferenly)

Comment: i don't get what you mean tho but you can wrap your include in an if statement to be run when a certain condition is met...

Comment: If you want to pull data from PHP without refreshing the page, then the solution is AJAX whether you like it or not. Or I suppose you could go with an iframe and just reload the frame.

Comment: (i dont want to pull data with ajax, because it dont work in this way for me) it could be calling an include php through javascript, do you know how do it?

Comment: `calling an include php through javascript` You mean you want to do that asynchronously? Like when using `AJAX`!?!

Comment: In seriousness AJAX appears to be exactly what you're asking for, but you don't seem to really know what it is so are saying you don't want to use it.

Comment: i used it already (request ajax), and thats why i am saying it dont work for me

Comment: how to update this include php each second then (in a php way)

Comment: For next time, please have a read about the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The question should have been about why your AJAX attempt didn't work rather than trying for force a solution that didn't make sense / wasn't possible as written.

Comment: The ajax request work well, I know do it but the big problem is that I am using datatable, so when I include the php data through include php inside my tag html tbody the field search (from datatable) in order to filter data it work well (with include php) but when I get php data through ajax require the data is included but the field search dont work when I do a data search. The data is included when I use ajax require but some functions from datatable dont work, for example: function of the filter data, field search. Do u understand, sorry if you think I forced you to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update only part of a page with PHP without using AJAX.   The Javascript AJAX call will run a PHP script that can access the database using PHP and will return the results.

You will need a Javascript function to make the AJAX call:

```
<script>
function jsupdate(returnid) {
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById(returnid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","databasecall.php,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

Then you will need a PHP script called "databasecall.php that accesses the database, so would contain something like:

```
//first include your database connection

 $sql = "SELECT * from mytable limit 1 ";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error: XXX000');
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  echo $row[0];
 }
 else {
   echo 'No such database table entry';
 }
```

The echo-ed results are returned to the Javascript.

Comment: how to include a php file through js then, because i dont want use an ajax request, it dont work in this case for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on when you are trying to update the info in the included page.

If you want to update it after the page has processed, you will have to use JavaScript + Ajax to load and update when necessary.

If on the other hand you are trying to do it while the page is still processing, you can use variables + objects + arrays to store the output data. That way you can update them when needed. Then at the end of processing you can actually output/echo/print the data.

Many people accomplish this by using the [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) extension in php, or using [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Comment: so how to define a time to update this information in this include php?

Comment: You don't define the time. If you just want the info to be updated before the page is loaded, use php. If the info needs to be updated after the page has loaded you will need to use javascript + ajax.

Comment: I reache a conclusion that do it just in js then, thanks all I gonna close this topic